# Bluetooth Isn't Working

Tags: bluetooth

I have bluetooth hardware and I already enabled it on sharing>bluetooth; but the icon doesn't appear on the top panel. My phone can't find my laptop and my laptop doesn't discover new devices. I tried asking on the irc channel but nobody answers. :(

Comment: Edit to include results for `lsusb; dmesg | egrep -i 'blue|firm'`

Answer (score 0):

eOS runs "bluez" can you find Bluetooth in system settings? if not what happens when you try "sudo apt-get install bluez" in the terminal?
For me, the Bluetooth window needs to be resized to show any devices while it is scanning.

Always be careful when using sudo.